# How do I configure system clock while using MBED IDE?

Tags: stm32, clock, stm32f4, mbed

Just starting to use STM32 boards with web-based [MBED IDE](https://www.mbed.com/en/).

This IDE don't have anything like *Project configuration* menu like other IDEs do. So I can not understand how do I configure system clock.

My board is [STM32F429I-DISC1](https://os.mbed.com/platforms/ST-Discovery-F429ZI/)

Comment: Typically that is done for you.  If you need to change it, you would need to ask in terms of the specific code being used.  IDE based configuration is not the usual; typically this is done by finding and editing the code responsible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanx! It seamed to be confusing for me as IDE in case of MBED making most of the boring things for me. So it seamed that the things such as clock configuration could be in a menu as a part of project main idea: making things easier.